# Bootstrap Nav menus won't style, what am I missing?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I have included these files in my **local build** within the `<head>` tag

```
<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<link href="./css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./css/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

before `</body>`:

```
<script src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The code I'm working with: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-default

Currently the navbar is appeared unformated/unstyled and don't understand exactly what I'm missing

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 3, you should change the tag for the question. Also, you should only include one CSS. Preferably `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: I have trimmed down the included .css files...
`<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="./css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="./css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

and I am using bootstrap-4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should only include one CSS file. `bootstrap(.min).css` **includes** grid and reboot. Check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files) for info about the CSS files.

And next, you are using the docs for Bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 4 has **major breaking** changes from version 3. So make sure to check that the docs are for v4. [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) are the docs for the navbar.

Also, some components need [PopperJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js), so make sure to include it aswell.

#### Here's an example navbar:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.

Comment: Cool! Make sure to accept the most helpful answer in your questions by clicking on the checkmark next to it. This will help other people searching for a solution for the same issue. :)